# String Split in PHP

Tags: php, string, split

Good afternoon all :)

I am trying to split a string in PHP however it's not as easy as it is in C#, it seems to be a tad bit messy...

I have a string, which looks something like this:

```
blahblah1323r8b|7.45
```

and I would like to be able to access the results of the split like this:

```
$var = split_result['leftside'];
$var = split_result['rightside'];
```

Is this easy to do in PHP? I'm trying to find some good examples, but the ones i've seen seem to be not what i'm trying to do, and a little over complicated (correct me if i'm wrong :))

Thank you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get an array:

```
$array = explode('|', $str);
```

Or to directly get two parts:

```
list($left, $right) = explode('|', $str);
```

See [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Just a comment: If you use *explode()* with *list()*, you should limit the result set to avoid, that something get lost: list($left, $right) = explode('|', $str, 2);

Comment: I will accept the answer when the timer runs out; Thanks for your help, and the code. That's about as easy as it is in c#, all the examples I saw required you to do a for-loop and iterate through all the chars - so very confusing!

Comment: @Lucifer: Thanks, and I'm surprised none of the examples you found actually mentioned `explode` - it's the most common way of splitting strings by a delimiter.